# Is it possible to store a Func<T> within a dictionary?

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, types

I'd like to be able to implement a dictionary with a key of `Type` and a value of `Func<T>` where `T` is an object of the same type as the key :

```
Dictionary<Type, Func<T>> TypeDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Func<T>>( ) /*Func<T> returns an object of the same type as the Key*/

TypeDictionary.Add( typeof( int ), ( ) => 5 );
TypeDictionary.Add( typeof( string ), ( ) => "Foo" );
```

So, basically, the dictionary would be populated with types that would reference a `Func<T>` which would return that value :

```
int Bar = TypeDictionary[ typeof( int ) ]( );
string Baz = TypeDictionary[ typeof( string ) ]( );
```

How can I go about implementing and enforcing this?

Comment: Is `T` the same for all elements within the dictionary?

Comment: There is no way to have strong typing. It wouldn't make sense, anyway. What's the type of `var thing = TypeDictionary[someType];` ? If you have `someType = typeof(int)`, it may be fairly obvious. But what happens if it's taken from `obj.GetType()` with `obj` cast as `object`? You can add methods which restrict the type, but you'll *always* have to end up with `Dictionary<Type, object>()` and cast it when retrieving the value.

Comment: No. T should be different for each entry in the dictionary... let me change my question to reflect...

Comment: @Dai if it is the dictionary will only have one entry.

Comment: As I can see, you have implemented it already, what else do you want to do?

Comment: @Rob So the dictionary would have to be `Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>` and I would when I call `(someType)TypeDictionary[someType]( )`? That's... reasonable I suppose...

Comment: @meJustAndrew Nothing's been implemented... In my example, `T` is defined no where, nor am I aware as to where or how I could/would be able to define it/pass it to `Dictionary.Add( ... )`

Comment: Oh, I get it now, but I have one more question: What could be the use case of this dictionary?

Comment: @meJustAndrew `TypeDictionary.Add( typeof( int ), int Bar => Bar * 5 )` `int Baz = TypeDictionary[typeof( int )]( 12 );` ( this is an absurdly simple example, of course, but is meant to illustrate the point - the dictionary is meant to store functions which will would manipulate and return values based on the type of the key ).

Comment: Now I get how this dictionary can be used, but I don't think it is a good practice to store Functions in a dictionary and bind them like this, but didactic, it is a good example!

Comment: @meJustAndrew Thanks for your feedback. The use case is, obviously, much more complex than this but also well beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is about as close as you're going to get:

```
void Main()
{
    var myDict = new MyWrappedDictionary();
    myDict.Add(() => "Rob");
    var func = myDict.Get<string>();
    Console.WriteLine(func());
}

public class MyWrappedDictionary
{
    private Dictionary<Type, object> innerDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    public void Add<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        innerDictionary.Add(typeof(T), func);
    }
    public Func<T> Get<T>()
    {
        return innerDictionary[typeof(T)] as Func<T>;
    }
}
```